# Dask cluster stuck when loading data with Open Data Cube

Tags: open-data-cube, dask

I'm running an ODC instance indexing and loading Sentinel-2 L2A COGs from the [Element84 bucket on AWS](https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-2-l2a-cogs/).
I use a Dask.distributed cluster deployed in "fixed" mode, for the definition of "fixed" provided [here](https://blog.dask.org/2020/07/23/current-state-of-distributed-dask-clusters#cluster-types).

Data access is very very slow due to the bucket being in the `us-west-2` region and my infrastructure being on a private cloud in Europe.
This wouldn't be much of a problem, except that on some random cases computations hang on some `dc_load_Bxx` Dask task, where `Bxx` is one of the Sentinel-2 L2A bands (it is not always the same one).
So basically, the cluster gets "idle", while only one task is in execution, but indefinitely.

Re-running the computation makes it successful, which indicates a temporary problem probably related to data access, but I'm not sure, as I cannot see any error or warning in the Dask scheduler/workers logs.

Any thoughts about things that might go wrong in my current setting, or any suggestion where I can start investigating?